# How can i run my Django server on google cloud with port 8000?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to running Django server on google cloud, How can i reflect my server on my domain.

Comment: Do you want the site served to the public on port 8000? Or do you want it served to the public on port 80, but listening locally on port 8000?

Comment: It will serve to the public on port 80, listening locally on port 8000.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because my Django server is running on local port 8000.

Comment: You can make your Django server listen on any port you like, however low-numbered ports (below 1024) require elevated permissions. The port default is 8000, but you can override that. Do a web search for "django listen port 80" to find options using gunicorn, nginx, iptables etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing among two very different things. Let's clarify them:

1. Django: Its the application stack which you are running and is controlled by you. You can ask it to run on any port >1024.
2. Google Cloud: The server where you will deploy your code to be accessible by anyone other than yourself.

Now the issue is, either you can give everyone an IP address and port number or you can use the preferred method of giving out a URL. Evidently you are working towards the easy way.

In order to do that, you need to do two things:

1. Point your domain name to the IP address of your Google Cloud compute instance
2. Run your Django server on port 80

This should start serving. But if not, make sure that you have allowed HTTP access to your instance. You can find that in cloud console.

Also you should try this: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AppEngine